# Trying to show that $E[1/X] = 1/E(X)$ is not true in general.

Tags: probability, expected-value

I know that one can use Jensens inequality and such, however I'm wondering if there is a more elementary proof not involving measure theory and Lebesgue-integration. For example something like this:

If we use LOTUS for the discrete case,
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \sum_{x}g(x)f_X(x),
\end{align}
for $g(X)=1/X$ we obtain
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]&=\sum_{x}\frac{f_X(x)}{x}\\
    \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[X]} &= \frac{1}{\sum_{x}xf_X(x)}.
\end{align}
Setting the two expressions above equal we obtain the equation
\begin{align}
    \left(\sum_x\frac{f_X(x)}{x}\right)\left(\sum_xxf_X(x)\right) = \sum_xf_X(x)^2 = 1.
\end{align}

So the sum of the pmf squared equals to 1. Is there any conclusion we can draw from here?

Comment: what do you mean by not true in general? Wouldn't finding a counterexample do? Or do you want to prove that the equality is never true except for constant X?

Comment: Let $X=1$ or $2$ depending on the flip of a fair coin.  Then $E(X)=3/2,$ and $E(1/X)=3/4.$ In general, you are comparing a mean to a harmonic mean.

Comment: Let $X=0$ or $1$, then $E[1/X]$ is not even defined.

Comment: In general, if $X$ is positive, you will have $E(1/X)\geq 1/E(X),$ with equality only when $X$ takes only one value. This is due the harmonic mean/arithmetic mean inequality.

Comment: @Ant - I want to prove that the equality is never true except for constant $X$.

Comment: @Parseval, what does constant $X$ as a r.v. mean? Do you assume $\Pr\{X=a\}=1$ for some $a\in \Bbb R$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz - well almost. I don't want to assume it, I want to prove that the pmf has to be $Pr(X=a)=1$ if the above should be true.

Comment: And how does $$\left(\sum_x\frac{f_X(x)}{x}\right)\left(\sum_xxf_X(x)\right) = \sum_xf_X(x)^2$$hold in general? You know that $$\sum a_i\sum b_i=\sum a_ib_i$$does not hold in general, right?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz - That's correct. I was too quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue by writing

$$ 1 = \sum_x f_X(x)^2 = \left(\sum_x f_X(x)\right)^2 - 2\sum_{x\neq y}f_X(x)f_X(y)$$

And since $\sum_x f_X(x)=1$, you find that it must be

$$\sum_{x\neq y}f_X(x)f_X(y) = 0$$

Since $f_X(x) \ge 0$ for every $x$, the only way for this to be true is that all the terms in the sum are 0. Now let's assume that there are 2 points $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $f_X$ is strictly greater than $0$. This would mean that
$$\sum_{x\neq y}f_X(x)f_X(y) \ge f_X(x_1)f_X(x_2) > 0$$ which is a contradiction. So we know that the pdf can be non-zero in at most one point $x_0$. But it also have to sum to 1, so there is precisely one point where the pdf is non zero, and in that point ($x_0$) it is equal to 1.

This implies that the random variable is a constant and equal to $x_0$.

Comment: If I compute $E(1/X)$ and $1/E(X)$ for $X=x_0$ by plugging this into the above sums they are not equal. How can this be?

Comment: You must have made a mistake. Assuming $x_0 \neq 0$, you see that     $$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]=\sum_{x}\frac{f_X(x)}{x} = \frac{f_X(x_0)}{x_0} = \frac {1}{x_0}$$ and this is of course equal to $\frac 1{E(X)}$ as $E(X) = x_0$